# Update state based on key in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have state structure, something like this at the beginning:

```
messages:[
        {id: 1, name: 'name1'},
        {id: 2, name: 'name2'}, ...
    ]
```

What I want is to update one message based on its `id` key. I am getting from the server another object like this:

```
{id: 2, name: 'newName2'}
```

The state is an array: `(2) [{…}, {…}]`. I don't know which element with which index will be updated, I know only the id key inside the object.

How I can update object inside the state based on its key value ?

Comment: Maybe store them as key value pairs, or reduce your list to an object. `messages.reduce ((m,o) => ({...m,[o.name]:o}),{})['name1']`. You could also use `messages.find(({name})=>name=='name1')`

Comment: Did any of the answers work for you? Consider [accepting one of them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#answer-5235) if that's the case.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) to get the index of the object you want to update, and replace that with the new object in a new array and set that in your component state.

**Example**

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    messages: [{ id: 1, name: "name1" }, { id: 2, name: "name2" }]
  };

  updateMessage(newMessage) {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      const messages = [...prevState.messages];
      const index = messages.findIndex(m => m.id === newMessage.id);

      messages[index] = newMessage;

      return { messages };
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.messages.map(message => (
          <div key={message.id}>{message.name}</div>
        ))}
        <button onClick={() => this.updateMessage({ id: 2, name: "newName2" })}>
          Update message
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You may be better of storing them as `{key:'value'}` pairs, if you need to look them up by a key.

You have a few options.

- If your key is the id, and matches the index, you can access it directly.
- Looping over your array
- Use `[].find`
- transform your list to an object and look it up.
- use [map](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54712972/1487756)
- or [findIndex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54712928/)
- ..etc

---

```
let id = 1
let message = messages [id -1];
message.foo = 'bar';
```

---

```
let prop = 'name', key = 'name1'
for (const message of messages) if (message[prop] === key) message.foo = 'bar'
```

---

```
const byProp = (prop,key) => ({[prop]:k}) => k == key
const message = messages.find (byProp('name', 'name1'))
```

---

```
const byProp = (arr,prop) => arr.reduce ((obj, itm) => ({...obj, [itm[prop]]:itm}),{})
let message = byProp (messages, 'name')['name1']
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
 const newMsg = { id: 10, message: 'hi' }

 this.setState(({ messages } => {
    return {
       ...messages.filter(x => x.id !== newMsg.id),
       newMsg
    }
 };
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Array.map` to modify your array

```js
const messages = [
    {id: 1, name: 'name1'},
    {id: 2, name: 'name2'},
]

const updateById = obj => {
  const { id } = obj;
  // here we check if new object has the same id as the old one
  // we replace old one with new
  return messages.map(message => message.id === id ? obj : message)
}

console.log(
  updateById({id: 1, name: 'newName'})
)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this. One among them can be like below.

```js
let x = [{id: 1, a: 1},{id: 2, b: 2}]

let newO = {id: 2, b: 3}

let y =[
    ...x.map(item => {
        if (item.id === newO.id) {
            return newO;
        } else return item
    })
]

console.log(y)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/qqvqxljy1j) that shows the code below in action.

Assuming you store your `state` like this:

```
    state = {
       messages: [
         { id: 1, name: 'name1' },
         { id: 2, name: 'name2' },
         { id: 3, name: 'name3' }
      ]
    }
```

Then, you can look for the message based on the id by using `findIndex()`, but you also want to make sure that you update your state immutably. So, you can do the following:

```
  changeMessage = (id, newName) => {

    // Search messages for a message with the given id, and return index
    // of the matching message in array, or -1 if not found.
    const arrayIndex = this.state.messages.findIndex((message) => (message.id === id))

    if (arrayIndex === -1) {
      console.log('No message found for id ' + id)
      return
    }

    // Copy over the messages from state to an array that
    // you can manipulate without affecting this.state.messages
    let updatedMessages = [...this.state.messages]

    // Update the message located by index
    updatedMessages[arrayIndex] = {
      id,
      name: newName
    }
    this.setState({
      messages: updatedMessages
    })
  }
}
```